# Operator | for choosing the data to load

Tags: r

I would like to use `if` to load the data from `csv` files which I determine at the beginning of my script.

I use this function:

```
if(which_data == "data1") {tbl <- read.csv("aaa.csv")}
```

but I would like to add operator OR `|` to load the data which I want if I put two different names to `which_data`.

The function should look like:

```
if(which_data == "data1" | "data2") {tbl <- read.csv("aaa.csv")}
```

but the problem is that such operator can be used only for numeric, logical or complex types. What else can I do ?

Comment: Try: `if(which_data == "data1"  |  which_data == "data2") { tbl <- read.csv("aaa.csv") }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test if your variable is "in" one of the values:

```
if(which_data %in%  c("data1" ,"data2")) {tbl <- read.csv("aaa.csv")}
```

Note that `|` doesn't do what maybe you think it does with numeric types:

```
> 3 == 2|3
[1] TRUE
> 3 == 2|1
[1] TRUE
```

Its testing `(3==2) or (1)`, and in R, `1` evaluates as `TRUE`, so the expression `3==2|1` is TRUE.